# Using humanize to convert numeric into words in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, humanize

I have some amount in numeric for e.g 75.00 and I am trying to convert it into words, for that I used humanize

```
75.humanize
```

But it keeps throwing error "undefined method humanize error for 75:Float"

Comment: @Ecnalyr She's talking about number to word humanize gem which works on integer and float

Comment: There is also rails method http://apidock.com/rails/String/humanize which works on string that will make the string human redable

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have installed [**`humanize`**](https://github.com/radar/humanize) gem

Now you can convert number to words

```
2.humanize     #=> "two"
4.humanize     #=> "four"
8.humanize     #=> "eight"

75.humanize    #=> "seventy-five" 
75.0.humanize  #=> "seventy-five point zero" 
75.00.humanize #=> "seventy-five point zero"
```

**NOTE:** Rails also has a [**`humanize`**](http://apidock.com/rails/String/humanize) method in string class which works differently